# Need help customizing moodlenet settings for my Moodle site

Tags: moodle

Moodle customize

Hi. I need to change the initial moodlenet texts in my moodlenet settings. In the picture below, I underlined the parts that I need to customize in red and I don't know what this part is for. If you know, can you explain it to me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5SCy.png)

I dont know how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

Site admin > General > Language > Language Customisation > [choose language] > Open language pack for editing

For filter settings, choose `tool_moodlenet` for the component

and `moodlenet settings` for strings containing

Enter your replacement string in the box for `local customisation`

Then save changes to the language pack